# Constructing 95% confidence intervals of coefficients in ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, arima

For the recurrence relation below I simulated it in R with arima.sim and used arima.sim(data, order=c(2,0,2)) to estimate the coefficients.

$x_t = x_{t-1} - \frac 13 x_{t-2} + w_t + \frac 14 w_{t-1}$

which gave the output:

```
arima(x = x.sim, order = c(2, 0, 2))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ma1     ma2  intercept
      0.7360  -0.1365  0.5229  0.1525    -0.1039
s.e.  0.2111   0.1486  0.2111  0.1155     0.1230

sigma^2 estimated as 0.8673:  log likelihood = -1348.58,  aic = 2709.15
```

and then I needed to find the 95% confidence intervals for the first coefficient of the AR and MA components and whether these two coefficients are in the interval. I wasn't sure how to construct the interval but I had read that it was (+- 2) * standard error of the coefficient but how does this work if I'm wanting the interval for the coefficient of the AR component and MA component? Once I have constructed the interval how could I determine if the interval contains the value of the coefficients?

Comment: "...whether these two coefficients are in the interval." What interval?

Comment: The 95% confidence interval

Comment: And what does it mean that the coefficient is in 95% confidence interval? If we are talking about the true value, then the 95% confidence interval covers the true value only 95% of the time, loosely speaking. Even with the 95% prediction intervals, the true value has 5% chance of being outside of the 95% prediction interval.